# How to change origin in Visual Studio Code to upload files to GitHub

Tags: github

I'm trying to change the origin when clicking Push To... in Visual Studio Code and it keeps showing me the wrong repository. How do I change the repo to save this completely different project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command-line for confirming you current local Git repository is associated to the wrong remote repository

```
cd c:\path\to\local\repository
git remote -v
```

And change it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/new_repository.git
```

VSCode should pick up on the new remote URL immediately.

Comment: That's beautiful and works. My frustration with GitHub.com and GitHub Desktop has just been extinguished. Thank you.

Comment: btw - if it's any help to anyone, I had to use git pull --force before being able to push to the new origin I just made. Please be warned that this was suitable for me and might not be suitable for you. 
Additionally, GitHub Desktop was not performing correctly and only the command line gave me any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **`push to`** option in the version control section...